# Step debugging through React code in Chrome issue

Tags: reactjs

I watched a couple tutorials and researched before asking but couldn't find an answer anywhere. When google for "React Debugging" most people show Chrome devtools with "Sources" tab that has "bundle.js" file and a "webpack" branch with all the sources that can be used to put breakpoints into to further debug application. But in my case none of that exists.

In fact when i run my application the only files I see listed below:

[image]

"main.bla-bla.js" is sorta like bundle with all the code, but there is nothing under the webpack:// for .js files!?

Developing my react app in visual studio if that matters.

Configure function out of startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

with webpack you need to enable devTool as source-map or cheap-eval-source-map so webpack will create sourcemaps for you and it will show under //webpack branch there.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: this is how my webpack.config.dev.js set:   devtool: 'source-map' - still same result

Comment: is your node environment set to development or production?

Comment: set to development

Comment: ah, I think instead of under //webpack your soucemaps are under that orange folder c:\Dev\.....

Comment: There is actually one file there, it sits in src/components/common/ but the files from src/components are not there. Looks like they are all compiled within the main......-unpate.js